# How to display Self Referencing Tables With Entity Framework in views

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have an self-referencing table with Categories, so I can have multiple subcategories on my page. My problem is, how do I get this data displaying in the View?

I want a dropdown with the parentcategory, that doesn't have any children, and when I click on the parentcategory the children could be seen in an new dropdownlist and so on until there are no more children.

Like this one http://www.dnasir.com/github/jquery-cascading-dropdown/demo.html just with a multiple dropdownslist.

My model for category looks like this :

```
public class Category
   {
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Fill in a Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Listing> Listings { get; set; }


    public int? ParentCategoryId { get; set; }

    public virtual Category ParentCategory { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Category> ChildCategories { get; set; }
}
```

My model for listings :

```
public class Listing
{
    public int ListingId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Fill in a Title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Fill in a Year")]
    [MinLength(4)]
    [MaxLength(4)]
    [Range(1910, 2033, ErrorMessage = "Year between 1910 and now")]
    public string Year { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Fill in a Price")]
    [Range(10.0, 1000000.0, ErrorMessage = "Price between 10-1000000")]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Quantity ?")]
    [Range(1, 2000, ErrorMessage = "Sell 1-2000 items")]
    public int Quantity { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Fill in a Location")]
    public string Location { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Make a description")]
    [MaxLength(300)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }

    public string ApplicationUserID { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Photo> Photos { get; set; }

}
```

My View :

```
@model ASPNetMarketplace.Models.Listing
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ListingCreate";
}
<h2>ListingCreate</h2>
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CategoryId, "CategoryId", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @*@Html.DropDownList("CategoryId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })*@

            @Html.DropDownList("CategoryId", ViewBag.CategoryId as SelectList, "Select a Category", new { id = "Category" })<br />

            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CategoryId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" id="saveButton" />
</div>
```

Hope someone could point me in the right direction, I have just started learning asp.net mvc.

Comment: The example link you have shown seems to be exactly what you're looking for - What bit are you having problems with?

Comment: I do not have a fixed number of subcategories